# TypeScript 4.2.1 Array.some() does not accept a function returning boolean

Tags: typescript

I'm seeing the following TypeScript error:

[image]

The full error message is:

> Supplied parameters do not many any signature of call target: parameter type mismatch. > Parameter 'Predicate' should have type assignable to
> {(value: TrackedItem, index: number, array: TrackedItem[]): typeof unknown; }'
> but it has type
> {(x: TrackedItem                                         ): boolean; }'

Why do these seemingly compatible variants not match up?

At this point I'm willing to believe it's the TypeScript typing that's being picked up being out of date or something. I've noticed if I change it to this, it works:

```
this.trackedItems().some((x => !x.isPutaway()) as any)
```

Comment: Please provide what typescript version you are using.

Comment: I've installed 2.4.1.

Comment: `unknown` type was introduces in Typescript 3.0 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) most likely this is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Did I say 2.4.1? Ha! I meant 4.2.1. Sorry for the confusion. I "fixed" it by casting to `any`. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` type was introduced in [Typescript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). If you are using version below Typescript 3.0 this might be the root cause.

Error message should be a bit different. I would expect to see error message:
`(value: TrackedItem, index: number, array: TrackedItem[]) => unknown` but you get `(value: TrackedItem, index: number, array: TrackedItem[]): typeof unknown`. In your case `unknown` is used as a value and it should be used as a type.

Tested on Typescript 4.3.2:

```
console.clear()

interface TrackedItem {
  item: number
}

const items: TrackedItem[] = [
  {
    item: 1
  },
  {
    item: 2
  }
]

const hasSome: boolean = items.some(x => x.item === 1)

console.log(hasSome) // prints true

// for:
//
// const hasSome: boolean = items.some((x: TrackedItem, y: string) => true)
//
// we get:
//
// Argument of type '(x: TrackedItem, y: string) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: TrackedItem, index: number, array: TrackedItem[]) => unknown'.
//   Types of parameters 'y' and 'index' are incompatible.
//     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```